# File upload using Flask without refresh

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I have user interface (angularJS) in which i need to upload a file without refreshing the page.Currently we are using Flask as web application framework.

I changed the index.html to below format so that without using **form** tags i am trying to read the uploaded file and store it.

Using **ngclick** method how to read the file from **app.py** ?

The following is the code snippet(index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Python Flask Bucket List App</title>
    <link href="http://bootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
         <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
         <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload file</button>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

code snippet of app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html') 

@app.route('/upload/')
def upload_file():
    print('uploaded file ',request.FILES['file1'].read())

    return render_template('signup.html')
```

I tried various options but i could not find feasible option.

Thanks
vijay

Comment: can you share your function `uploadFile()`?

Comment: In app.py i am using below snippet to read the file.  It is throwing the error invalid syntax. Please suggest how can i take it forward.                          $scope.uploadFile = function()
 {
        $http.post('/', $scope.request)
            success(function(){alert('ok')})
            error(function(){alert('fail')});
  }

Comment: Please add your whole controller myCtrl to your question-post. Most probable that problem is in js code.